# 413 Error: Uploading to OneDrive API using Sessions

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, large-files

I have a React.js app that is suppose to upload large files to Microsoft OneDrive through their API. I have a test file that is around 3GB (2975226488 bytes) and I am dividing up the file into 327680 bytes at a time. But at the very first range [0-327680] bytes, the API is responding back with 413 error.

Here I am creating a session and getting back a session url.

```
            const sessResp = await fetch(`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/Dropzone/${filename}:/createUploadSession`, {
                method: "POST",
                headers: headers
            });
            const sessParsed = await sessResp.json();
```

Then I am getting ranges for my file to upload at a time because according to the docs it's suppose to be in multiples of 320Kib (327,680 bytes). [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createuploadsession?view=odsp-graph-online#cancel-the-upload-session)

```
            let ranges = []; 
            for (let a = 0; a < filesize; a+=327680) { //320 KiB (327,680 bytes)
                ranges.push(a); 
            }
            ranges.push(filesize);
```

Then, I am looping through my ranges array and making a request each range at a time to upload my file to OneDrive.

```
          for (let i = 0; i <= ranges.length; i++) { 
                let uploadSize = filesize > 327680 ? 327680 : ranges[1]; // if filesize is smaller than 327680 then only 2 elements in ranges
                
                let fileheaders = new Headers();
                fileheaders.append("Authorization", bearer);
                fileheaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
         
                fileheaders.append("Content-Length", uploadSize);

                fileheaders.append("Content-Range", `bytes ${ranges[i]}-${ranges[i+1]-1}/${filesize}`);
                const resp = await fetch(sessParsed.uploadUrl, {
                    method: "PUT",
                    headers: fileheaders, 
                    body: binaryStr
                });


            }
```

Comment: What is the value of `binaryStr`? From the provided code it doesn't appear that it represents the bytes for the range, but is rather the entirey 3GiB. You need to make sure the number of bytes provided in `body` matches the `uploadSize` that you're using to set the `Content-Length`

Answer (score 0):

## Use Streams to upload documents

### Over time, this upload feature may not scale well in terms of performance.

Check out this article : https://medium.com/@vecera.petr/how-to-handle-large-file-upload-with-nodejs-express-server-7de9ab3f7af1